# Etherpad: Best Way to hook into auth

Tags: node.js, express, etherpad

I'm making a plugin for etherpad that checks if the user is authenticated. If not it displays the read only. I got this far:

```
var eejs = require('ep_etherpad-lite/node/eejs');
var readOnlyManager = require("ep_etherpad-lite/node/db/ReadOnlyManager");

exports.route = function(hook_name, args, cb){
    args.app.get('/p/:pad', function(req, res){
        if(req.params.pad.indexOf('r.') === 0){
            res.send(eejs.require("ep_etherpad-lite/templates/pad.html", {req: req}));
        } else {
            if(req.session.user){
                res.send(eejs.require("ep_etherpad-lite/templates/pad.html", {req: req}));
            } else {
                readOnlyManager.getReadOnlyId(req.params.pad, function(err, readonlyID){
                    res.redirect('/p/'+readonlyID);
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

exports.logout = function(hook_name, args, cb){
    args.app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
      req.session.destroy(function(){
        res.redirect('/');
      });
    });
}
```

But I can't use post routes to make my own user login. How can I have something like the general authentication on request, let's say when I visit /login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a lot of the auth mechanism in Etherpad but it was years ago and I don't know how much it's changed since.

The API endpoints you need and documentation for how auth works is available in the [Etherpad documentation](http://etherpad.org/doc/v1.3.0/) and specifically auth is discussed in the [authentication documentation](http://etherpad.org/doc/v1.3.0/#index_overview).

It's hard to tell from your question but it looks like you want to have some sort of login page at /login?  If so, review how Etherpad already implements basic auth and adapt it by creating a new express endpoint at /login

There are various plugins (including ones I have developed) that can be used to create new express endpoints, [an example is available in the ep_email_notifications Etherpad plugin](https://github.com/JohnMcLear/ep_email_notifications/blob/master/index.js#L9)

Did I get the right end of the stick from your question?

Comment: Partly yes :) I tried a **itload of things already and can't seem to get it work. But pointing to the auth docs, I'll have to read them more carefully.